# Proof in field of quotients (form of elements)

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Let $R$ be an unique factorization domain. Being an integral domain, it has a field of quotients $F$. We can consider $R[x]$ to be a subring of $F[x]$.

> Given any polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$, then $f(x)=(f_0(x)/a)$, where $f_0(x)\in R[x]$ and where $a\in R$.

I don't understand why $a\in R$, in the proof of the theorem that Every integral domain can be imbedded in a field, we used $a/b$, where $a,b$ where in the integral domain. So why in this example above we have $a/b$ where $a\in R[x]$ and $b\in R$?

Comment: This is simply a different proof, and the specifics are largely unrelated.

Comment: Well, he uses the fact that being a integral domain, we apply the theorem proved earlier to talk about the field of quotient $F$, or any idea to proceed in the proof of the statement?

Comment: Yes, it's actually quite easy. Think about what happens when $R=\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F[x]$ is the set of polynomials of $x$ with coefficients in $F$, the field of quotients of $R$. You may be thinking of $F(x)$, the field of rational polynomials (field of quotients of $R[x]$.

Comment: ooh! i think i'm getting it now thanks, im going to try and prove it now

Answer (score 1):

The point is that we can choose a *common* denominator for all the fractional coefficients (e.g. the product or lcm of the denominators), which allows us to rewrite it in said form, just like every polynomial in $\,\Bbb Q[x]\,$ can be written as the quotient of a polynomial with *integer* coeff's and *integer* denominator.